# VS Code lost outline panel?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Where did the panel disappear to?

see screen 1 for open folder "outline1"

[image]

see screen 2 for open folder "outline2"

[image]

Comment: Ctrl + Shift + P > in the command Palette > Preferences: Reset Settings.  then Ctrl + Shift + P >  View: Close All Views, then see if the panels load?

Comment: reset settings is a bit nuclear. I'd try `View: Reset View Locations` in the command palette first (still a bit nuclear, but _much less so_). Also, what do you see in the three-dot menu?